# How to load valid current days in rails date_select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have used date_select :filter, :start_date in my application. I need to load valid date for current month. for example default date loaded for february month is 1 to 31 but need to load actual days for February (1 to 28).

How to resolve ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the activesupport helpers for date to get the start and end of the month and then add that into a range. Once you have the range then you can pass that to options_from_collection_for_select.

For example:

```
<% range = (DateTime.now.beginning_of_month .. DateTime.now.end_of_month) %>
<%= select_tag :date, 
      options_from_collection_for_select(
        range.collect{|d|['date', d.mday]}, :first, :last) %>
```

Comment: Hi Roo, Is there any option in rails date_select tag?